# Помогите понять задачу

Tags: java

На данный момент прохожу массивы.
Хочу разобраться в том, как это работает.
Обилие переменных и ссылок немного сбивает с толку.
Собственно вот задача

```
public class HeapQuiz {
int id = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 0;
    HeapQuiz [] hq = new HeapQuiz[5];
    while(x < 3) {
        hq[x] = new HeapQuiz();
        hq[x].id = x;
        x = x + 1;
    }
    hq[3] = hq[1];
    hq[4] = hq[1];
    hq[3] = null;
    hq[4] = hq[0];
    hq[0] = hq[3];
    hq[3] = hq[2];
    hq[2] = hq[0];
    }   
 }
```

Цель задачи определить какая переменная ссылается на какой объект
id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                   01234
hq[3] = hq[1];     01214
hq[4] = hq[1];     01211
hq[3] = null;      012-1
hq[4] = hq[0];     012-0
hq[0] = hq[3];     -12-0
hq[3] = hq[2];     -1220
hq[2] = hq[0];     -1-20
```

Comment: hq0 , hq1 = id1, hq2, hq3 = id2, hq4 = id0    такой ответ я нашел в книге . вместе с Вашим ответом ситуация немного прояснилась, но не до конца

Comment: выходит, что номер индекса переменной приравнивается к номеру индекса другой переменной . затем туда помещается id и в цикле проверяется условие  x < 3 . или я понял не верно?

Comment: @ДмитрийЛевицкий, нет. По крайней мере, правильной терминологией в комментарии даже не пахнет. И правдоподобным описанием - тоже. Да и в вопросе так себе. И ты вообще не используешь слово "объект", а "ссылка" упоминается как-то вскользь.

Comment: @ДмитрийЛевицкий, по принципиально неправильной терминологии может быть видно непонимание. Посмотри ещё раз про объекты ссылочные типы данных.